# Left join on first value from right table?

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, greatest-n-per-group

I need to do left join on table under conditions, so value from left table picks only first value found in right table, sorted by time, and that time in right table is > than time in left.

How that can be done?

Thanks.

Comment: This probably deserves the `[greatest-n-per-group]` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps a construct like this (using sub-query rather than a join):

```
SELECT (SELECT TOP 1 D2.DiDateEnd
    FROM Diary AS D2
    WHERE D2.DiDateEnd > D1.DiDateEnd
    ORDER BY D2.DiDateEnd) AS RightTableTime, *
FROM Diary AS D1
```

Have used one of my own tables for the sample, since you didn't provide table/column names.

Comment: This example uses the same table upon itself, but D1 and D2 could just as well be different tables, if such was your scenario.